# Sonar 5.1.1 "Unable to create symbol table" error

Tags: sonarqube

I'm running a sonarqube server version 5.1.1, and when running maven analyzer with "mvn sonar:sonar" I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [12:54:13.778] Unable to create symbol table for : /Users/rodrigouchoa/Java/git/spread/mj/wicket-exemplo/Build/Codigos_Fonte/wicket-exemplo-parent/wicket-exemplo-web/src/main/java/br/gov/mj/wicket/exemplo/web/service/SegurancaService.java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve type parameter: PK in class IGenericPersister
```

Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The java plugin for sonarqube was [recently updated](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava). Try to update it and check if the problem is fixed.